# EXCEL SUMIFS IN R using ddply

Tags: r, excel, apply, plyr, sumifs

Im trying to implement a SUMIFS logic for the following table that I have implemented in EXCEL (Column A, B, C respectively):

```
ID  x   y
123 3   50
123 2   -10
123 4   -20
124 3   50
124 2   -10
124 4   -20
```

1. Create a new vector z using the formula:

> =IF(C2>0;(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$7;$A$2:$A$7;A2;$B$2:$B$7;">="&B2));C2)

2. Copy the formula down to populate the vector z and it works.
3. For each row, if "y" > 0 the formula adds values of "y" if the ID is the same and the value of "x" is greater than the value of "x" in the current row.

In R, I have tried to write a ddply function but Im struggling to bed in a for loop within. So here is where Im at:

> ddply(test,.(ID,x), mutate,  z = function(y))

I have similarly tried with "summarise" but the problem of conditions remain.
I would appreciate any help in defining function (y) so that I can get an equivalent excel result. Many Thanks.

Comment: What result were you expecting and what did you get? I put this on a spreadsheet and it seems to be working but I don't know what you are expecting. I get 30, -10, -20, 30, -10, -20.

Comment: Hi Tim - agreed, the formulas work in excel. Im looking for a way to do this in R using ddply or any other suitable function.

Comment: Ah, that's where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit brute force and probably not the best approach, but it replicates the Excel output:

```
# sample data:
df <- read.table(text = 'ID  x   y
                 123 3   50
                 123 2   -10
                 123 4   -20
                 124 3   50
                 124 2   -10
                 124 4   -20', header = TRUE)

# create a new column called 'sum_y' using the defined rules:
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (df$y[i] > 0) df$sum_y[i] = sum(df$y[df$x >= df$x[i] & df$ID == df$ID[i]])
  else df$sum_y[i] = df$y[i] 
}

# view the output:
df
   ID x   y sum_y
1 123 3  50    30
2 123 2 -10   -10
3 123 4 -20   -20
4 124 3  50    30
5 124 2 -10   -10
6 124 4 -20   -20
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your formula into a sheet and modified it as below...

```
=IF(C2>0,(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,A2,$B$2:$B$7,">="&B2)),C2)
```

I changed the semi-colons to commas.

The results I got...

[image]